# Is it possible to validate immediately after clicking on Button.

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to validate immediately after clicking on Button.

Assume, there is submit button. And i need to click on Submit button and before the next page load i need to validate submit button is disabled...

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some more information...

Comment: How about http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getEval(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can perform a nonblocking click by using either one of these:

[The Advanced User Interactions API](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#advanceduserinteractions) ([JavaDocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html))

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.whatever("anything"));
new Actions(driver).click(element).perform();
```

or JavaScript:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.whatever("anything"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Both these solutions will immediatelly return the browser control to your hands, so you can validate your data before the page gets unloaded.