# Selenium, ignore load time while clicking on multiples tabs

Tags: performance, dom, web-applications, browser, selenium

I have the following situation:

I'm using Selenium 2.35, programming on Java, Using FireFox. I build a program that open multiple tabs on the web browser and interact with them.

When I click on a element of the web site, Selenium waits until the page loads before continue working, but since I'm using multiples tabs I want to click the button on each tab almost at same time without wait for page to load on each before click on the next one.

The question is this:

Is there a way I can click on all those buttons on different tabs without having to wait until the page loads?

This is my code:

```
for(int i = 2; i < cant ; i++){

  ((FirefoxDriver)driver).getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+Integer.toString(i));
  driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());
  driver.findElement(By.id("Registrar")).click();

}
```

Comment: What selenium are you using? Java? Selenium IDE (the firefox plugin)?

Comment: I update the question, i'm working with Java

Comment: A similar question was actually asked and answered by Slanec a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765073/is-it-possible-to-validate-immediately-after-clicking-on-button/18766099#18766099

Comment: Nope didn't work Slanec's answers, i tested them, it still wait util the browser give back the control, a way to test it is just disconnect the pc from internet and see if he keep doing stuff or just waiting util the web finish to load.